# Product/intersection of two ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ be two ideals in polynomial ring $C[u,v,t]$, defined as $I_1 = \langle t-u^3, (v-u^5)^2\rangle$ and $I_2 = \langle u^{11} + v^{11} + t^{11} + 3\rangle$. Is there a method for showing (by hand) that $I_{1} I_{2} = I_{1} \cap I_{2}$? Also, is there a formula for computing the radical of $I_{1} \cap I_{2}$? The details and references are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $I_1\cdot I_2$ instead of $\dot I_2$?

Comment: Computing the product is easy; the difficulty is computing the intersection. The standard algorithmic methods are via Gröbner bases; see for instance chapter 15 in Eisenbud's *Commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry*. One method is given in §15.10.8, and two others in exercises 15.42 and 15.43. (I find the last of these the most intuitive, but I don't really know which one is algorithmically the easiest.) Computing the radical using Gröbner bases is mentioned but not covered.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and references.